# Android Hide view on AbsListview scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, android-relativelayout

I have a weighted layout that has a Relative Layout with a  ViewPager on top,followed by a linearLayout and another LinearLayout containing a List ( GridView for tablets and ListView for Mobile). What I want to do is to smoothly hide the top ViewPager Relative Layout when the user is scrolling the list. I currently have code that abruptly hides the top view when scrolling. Below is by current code.

XML for the mobile (Tablets layout is the same except that the ListView is a GridView):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/liveHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".60" 
    android:background="@color/black">

    <com.custom.model.LivePagerContainer
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/livePager"
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
   </com.custom.model.LivePagerContainer>        

</RelativeLayout>

  <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:background="@color/light_gray"
   android:dividerHeight="1dp">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="34dp"
       android:layout_height="34dp"
       android:contentDescription="@string/image"
       android:cropToPadding="true"
       android:maxHeight="24dp"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:src="@drawable/image" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/titleBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:text="@string/string"
       android:textColor="@color/black"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>    
   <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight=".40">
      <ListView
             android:id="@+id/ListView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:divider="@color/light_gray"
             android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
         </ListView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

current code to hide/animate:

```
private AbsListView listView;

....
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
        int scrollState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view,
        int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
        int totalItemCount) {
    RelativeLayout live = (RelativeLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.liveHome);
    if(firstVisibleItem >2)
    {
        TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-live.getHeight());
        animate.setDuration(500);
        animate.setFillAfter(true);
        live.startAnimation(animate);
        live.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        live.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}                       
});
```

The problem is that the current code ( using setVisibility() hides the "liveHome" relative layout correctly) is very abrupt. I want to make it smoothly slide up out of the screen as I scroll the listview. I tried adding animation as well. The animation code in the onScroll "moves" the content out of the screen but then I am left with empty space for my top section (that is until the setVisibility(View.GONE) abruptly makes the blank space disappear).

Is there a way for me to hide the RelativeLayout smoothly? Any help will be appreciated.

Note: I am using AbsListView in my code since i dynamically use a ListView or Gridview based on my device( phones vs tablets) so I cannot use the ListView's addHeaderView.